# convert array of objects into InputStream

Tags: java, unit-testing

I have the program I want to test:

```
while(true) {
//useful code
    try {
        id = inputValue();
    } catch (InputMatchException e) {
        System.out.println("blahblah");
    }
}


public int inputValue() throws IOException {
    InputStream inputStream = ???
    System.setIn(inputStream);
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    return scanner.nextInt();
}
```

Here I want that *inputValue* returns string at first iteration and results in **catch** block and second time returns 0. Is it possible to do? The loop has conditions to exit) No worries about it.

Answer (score 0):

Use `ByteArrayInput/OutputStreams`.

```
ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

out.write("My string\n".getBytes());
out.write("0".getBytes());

ByteArrayInputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(out.toByteArray());
```

Then read from `in` with the Scanner.

You don't even need the `inputValue()` method, since you'll just want to call `scanner.nextInt()` when its set up.